# Android netrunner data and destiny deck lists

Tags: android-netrunner

As the data and destiny expansion did not come with any deck lists I was wondering if anyone had tips for how to construct decks for these new runners Apex, Adam and Sunny Lebeau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!
Instead of answering here, I'll link you to [netrunnerdb](http://netrunnerdb.com/). It is one of several sites that provide tools for building and sharing Android: Netrunner decks. If you are looking for ideas around a specific card or group of cards, you can do a query like [this one](http://netrunnerdb.com/en/decklists/find?faction=&cards[]=09037&author=&title=&sort=popularity&packs[]=1&packs[]=8&packs[]=21&packs[]=28&packs[]=35&packs[]=2&packs[]=3&packs[]=4&packs[]=5&packs[]=6&packs[]=7&packs[]=9&packs[]=10&packs[]=11&packs[]=12&packs[]=19&packs[]=18&packs[]=22&packs[]=23&packs[]=24&packs[]=25&packs[]=26&packs[]=27&packs[]=29&packs[]=30&packs[]=31&packs[]=32&packs[]=33&packs[]=34) to see decks other people have built that include that card.